# Problem with NativeScript 7.0 installation

Tags: nativescript

I am using the following commands in the terminal on OSX (with and without sudo):

To uninstall previous version: **npm uninstall -g nativescript** and **sudo npm remove -g nativescript**

Then to install NS 7.0: **npm i -g nativescript**

When trying to use **ns clean** or **ns create** commands I have got this error:

***zsh: command not found: ns***

Please let me know what may cause this problem... Thank you

Comment: tns create, not ns.

Comment: Thank you @Yong, new nativescript 7.0 is supporting ns along with tns

Comment: You are right, I did not notice ns. Nativescript cli's changelog does not update.

Comment: Seems like **brew upgrade node** command helped